# How to handle socket error connection closed exception while loading huge data using SpringData MongoDB repository.saveAll()

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using springdata-mongodb & loading huge amount of data. While loading we're sometime seeing

```
Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:10, serverValue:111926}] to *.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 because there was a socket exception raised by this connection
```

Here's what we're doing

1. Running a simple app in some 20 pods inside GCP
2. All apps trying to MongoRepository.saveAll({huge list})
3. A scheduler is invoked to read data{domain object} from an instance variable and store into the DB
4. We did not specify any batch size assuming springdata-mongodb will take care of it for us
5. These documents have id, so basically we're trying to upsert
6. No two pods will have documents with duplicate ids, the app takes care of it
7. Most of the pods run successfully, but atleast 2 or 3 pods seem to face the above connection issue

Our connection string in application.yml looks like below:

```
data:
mongodb:
  uri: mongodb+srv://${MONGODB_USER}:${MONGODB_SECRET}@*.gcp.mongodb.net/my-db-name?retryWrites=true&w=majority&minPoolSize=0&maxPoolSize=100&maxIdleTimeMS=300000
```

I'm looking for some inputs on how to handle this exception, my-questions are:

1. Is it only the current connection that has issue? or all connection from pool?
2. If we encounter this issue for the current scheduled job can we safely ignore this? assuming that the next scheduled job will get a different connection and will update DB successfully?

Comment: The driver will retry writes automatically, a single socket error shouldn't be a cause for concern.

Comment: The driver does that for you. If you are receiving network errors, your network is unreliable and I suggest splitting the data into smaller pieces or processing it closer to the database where the network is reliable.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for confirming @D.SM .

So, in the above scenario I believe I just have to handle the exception and let the next job process the data. The new job will be a new thread and it might obtain a working connection from the pool and the driver takes care of assigning a working pool I believe. Please correct me if I'm wrong here.. Thanks !